# Global Path not appearing in rviz

Tags: navigation, rviz, plugin

Hello I been trying using my own global planner as a plugin and I think my planner worked but the path is not appearing in rviz.So I tried searching problems in the Internet and I was not sure about some issues so I'm leaving my question here

1. is move_base.xml and move_base.launch.xml is different?
2. if "Got new plan" message appears in the terminal then my planner made the correct plan(path)?
   3)Should I make a publish node to my own global_planner?(Im inherting nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner)

Im using ROS melodic and I changed the base_global_planner param on move_base.xml to use my own planner
Thanks for reading my question and if somebody knows plz leave a comment

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.